# Disable registration route in Yesod.Auth.Email

Tags: yesod

How can I disable registration route (`registerR :: AuthRoute`) in Yesod.Auth.Email plugin? I want to disable only possibility of registration after a certain period of time.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the `addUnverified` and `registerHandler` methods (in the YesodAuthEmail typeclass).

```
instance YesodAuthEmail App where
    addUnverified _ _ =
        sendResponseStatus status503 ("User registration is unavailable now" :: Text)

    registerHandler =
        sendResponseStatus status503 ("User registration is unavailable now" :: Text)
```

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/yesod-auth-1.4.12/docs/Yesod-Auth-Email.html